# Hydraulic brakes accidentally oiled

Tags: disc-brake, lubricant

Please help me. When I'm using my hydraulic brake I hear a weird sound. I think putting oil on it will cure the problem but I guess it just come out worse. After putting oil my brakes they are not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you think you have screwed up with your brakes, then the safest way to proceed is to find a qualified bicycle mechanic to fix it for you. The brakes is the area where you do not really want to learn by trial and error.

Answer (score 8):

Braking surfaces (pads, rims, rotors) must *never* be lubricated in any way. Doing so can severely affect braking performance and is dangerous.

You can clean the rotor with isopropyl alcohol or mineral spirits.

The pads will probably have to be replaced as oil permeates into the pad material. You might be able to save them by cleaning with alcohol and sanding off the top layer, but replacement is the safest option.

Answer (score 2):

You can read through this guide to clean your disc brakes [How to clean disk brakes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/54373/19442).

Never put anything on your braking surfaces, that includes your fingers. Beside oils and acid from your skin, you can burn yourself.

If you are getting noises from braking, you need to start looking at the brake alignment, contaminants and loose axles.

In your case, you will need to carefully clean out the calipers to as the oil would have transferred in there.